# Regex validation of string, dash and closing string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've tried several patterns and fiddling with some pattern from [Capture word between optional hyphens regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768612/capture-word-between-optional-hyphens-regex),
[Regular Expressions: How to find dashes between words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880550/regular-expressions-how-to-find-dashes-between-words),
[What's the difference between "(\w){3}" and "(\w{3})" in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741265/whats-the-difference-between-w3-and-w3-in-regex) and also read [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

My best attempt so far was:
`(\w{3}\-)`

with test data:

> THU-abs-sss-ddd
>
> 012-aa-aaa-aaa

which match:

[image]

---

Despite what I would like to achieve is an exact pattern validation against:
XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX where XXX is 3 alphanumeric and dash repeated 3 times and closed with another XXX alphanumeric.

I've also tried using `(\w{3}\-)(\w{3})`
but then the result was:

[image]

---

What am I missing to complete the pattern?

Comment: `^\w{3}(?:-\w{3}){3}$`. Quantify the group closer to the end of pattern, it is best practice. `^` matches the start of string and `$` matches the end of string, use these anchors if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the `\w{3}-` group 3 times:

```
(?:\w{3}-){3}\w{3}
```

(note that `-` doesn't need to be escaped, and that you should use non-capturing groups unless you *really need* to capture)